# Collection of Large String too slow with Kotlin Flow

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

In MyDataSource class I am emitting a flow of type String. This string can be large; up to 50k characters long. I'm then collecting this in MyViewModel. The problem I have is, due to the size of the string, the flow collector in the view model seems very slow. The flow builder emits several values per second, but the collector will only collect once every 1 or 2 seconds, creating a noticeable lag.

I have also tried holding myString in MyDataSource as a StateFlow and collecting that in the view model instead, but it has similar issues.

I have tested by reducing the size of the string and the performance improves.

How can I improve this so that it's more performant? Can I compress the string somehow, or is Kotlin Flow the wrong tool for the job? In an ideal world I need to receive all values at very fast speed, with little to no drops.

I've deliberately changed the code to hide true functionality (I am not displaying a 50k character string to the screen!).

```
@Singleton
class MyDataSource @Inject constructor() : MyDataChangedListener() {

    private var _myString = "Initial Value"
    val myString = _myString

    //data can be up to 50000 characters long
    override fun onDataChanged(data: String) {
        super.onDataChanged(data)
        _myString = data
    }

    val myFlow: Flow<String?> = flow {
        while(true) {
            emit(myString)
        }
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val myDataSource: MyDataSource 
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _myCurrentString = MutableStateFlow<String>("Initial Value")
    val myCurrentString = _myDisplayString.asStateFlow()

    fun getMyDataSourceString() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                myDataSource.myFlow.collect {
                    _myCurrentString.value = "Message: $it"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Flow doesn't care about the size of the string. It will work exactly the same with empty strings as with 50k strings. As you said, your bottleneck is the collector which we don't even see here.

Comment: Well, assigning a value to `MutableStateFlow` could potentially be slow as it compares stings to each other. But that would affect the performance in very specific cases only, e.g. if strings start with kilobytes of same chars and it would be still pretty fast - definitely not once every 1-2 seconds.

Comment: @broot I've included the collector in the view model. If I remove the _myCurrentString.value assignment and replace with a Log, and also put a Log next to the emit, then the Log next to the emit prints many more times than the Log inside .collect {}

Comment: That sounds very strange. Flows support backpressure and that means we can't emit more than we collect. `emit()` waits for the collector (assuming we don't use buffers). If you put a delay in the collector, that should proportionally slow down the emitter as well.

Comment: Having a loop that emits value of your string infinite amount of times in an endless (but cancellable) loop is just bad. How about you put mutable state flow in your data source instead and your viewmodel can properly collect it with a flow that just adds "Message: " part to it.

Comment: @Pawel I said in the post "I have also tried holding myString in MyDataSource as a StateFlow and collecting that in the view model instead, but it has similar issues." I don't receive every value in the collection that is emitted

Comment: Ok, I'm guessing you don't want to use state flow at all then because it behaves like conflated flow... shared flow with buffer maybe but then you will probably end up overflowing it if collection is indeed slow.. Could it be that creating new string (`"Message: $it"`) is the bottleneck?